# SVG JS - text color

Tags: svg.js

Hei,I'm trying to change the text color of a text that I'm adding using svg js.
my code looks like this:

```
var elecChangeText=elecChange.toString();
var elecPercentageText = energyArrow.text(elecChangeText);

elecPercentageText.font({
    family:   'Helvetica', 
    size:     30, 
    color: "#ffffff", 
})
elecPercentageText.cx(energyArrow.cx());
elecPercentageText.cy(energyArrow.cy());
```

but the text appears in black anyways. any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to use `text-color` instead of just `color`, but that throws an error...

Comment: Could you take a look to my answer ? did it work ?

Comment: sorry was busy with other things. but yes it's working well! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fill` attribute instead.

I've created a JSFiddle with a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ufFn/

```
var draw = SVG('mysvg').size(500, 500)
var txt = draw.text("Colored text")
txt.font({
  family:   'Helvetica', 
  size:     30, 
  fill: '#ff0000'
})
```

Comment: But how do I get the current element's color? I tried with txt.font().fill but with no result..

Comment: Try: `txt.attr('fill')`